# Roboto Condensed google font falls back in all browsers

Tags: css, fonts, rendering, roboto

I have several google fonts which I import into stylesheet with using @import rule. All of them render fine except of Roboto Condensed. It falls back to default sans-serif font, in my case Helvetica.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400&subset=latin,latin-ext);

font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
```

I already tried removing local Roboto font, changing font-weight and font style, playing with font-family name but dev tools still show that the rendered font is Helvetica. Other Google fonts render just fine. What could be an issue?

Answer (score 5):

Included `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400&subset=latin,latin-ext);` in my stylesheet and

```
html, body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

worked just fine for me. Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: no other errors. It doesn't work in neither Chrome, nor FF or Safari. Two other google fonts load fine.

Comment: figured out it only works when it's added via link tag ("standard" way) to the head. Weirdly enough the problem only exists for Roboto Condensed while other google fonts work properly when added with @import.

Comment: question here is ¿why?